# need edit my code vb.net console and form

Tags: vb.net, cmd, console

hello i build programe by vb.net console and run good but i need build it in form and edit some thing in code

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
```

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Process.Start("cmd", "/k netsh wlan show profile name=test key=clear")


End Sub
```

End Module

its code run good but i need edit in part "name=test to textbox1.text to write name profile by me beacuse if i change test to any name not show password and need build it in vb.net but form

Comment: So go ahead and do that then.  If you encounter any specific issues while doing so, post back here and show us exactly what you've done and explain exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the solution you are expecting

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k netsh wlan show profile name=" & textbox1.Text & " key=clear")
```

Comment: can i add some function now when i do it in form it will open cmd so can i change color cmd , color background , ?